# jQuery-mobile and ASP.NET combination issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile solution with a combination of jQuery.mobile and
asp.net webforms.

For postbacks of my asp.net controls to work properly I have to disable ajax at
the top of the page, like this:

```
   <script>
      $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
   </script>
```

But when ajax is disabled like this, other functions doesn't seem to work.
I can't call dialogs/popups from jQuery document ready

For example:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {        
     $('#myPopup').popup('open'); 
  });
```

This will just cause the popup to show in less than a second,
then it dissapears. Also when I register a clientscript
from codebehind to trigger the popup when a serverside button
is clicked, the popup just flashes, then dissapears. 
But when I disable ajax at the top of the page, the popup
calls works fine.

Any ideas how to get around these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document ready can not be successfully used with **`jQuery Mobile`**. It will usually trigger before page **`DOM`** is populated.

Instead of this line:

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $('#myPopup').popup('open'); 
});
```

Use this line:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page-id', function(){       
    $('#myPopup').popup('open'); 
});
```

Where **`#page-id`** is an id of page that contains that popup.

jQuery Mobile has a problem with document ready so its developers have created page evenets to remedy this problem, read more about it in this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)** or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

**EDIT :**

I think your problem is also in **`$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;`** handling.

That code sample **MUST** be triggered from **`mobileinit`** event like this:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

One more thing, **`mobileinit`** event **MUST** be triggered before **`jQuery Mobile`** is initialized, like this:

```
<script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>      
<script>
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        });    
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply. I tried to change to 'pagebeforeshow' but it still only works if I set $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;

Comment: Lets to it step by step. Did you disabled ajax inside a mobileinit event? Ajax can not be disabled like this: <script>$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;</script>

Comment: Hi, I'm getting closer, but not there yet. It is a kind of strange  workflow in JQM. I now have:

    $(document).on('pageinit', function () {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        });  

And then a button event in my codebehind with:

  Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "popup", "$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#mobile_page', function () { $('#alert').popup('open'); });", True)

Response.Write("test")

The problem is that any code after the call of the popup is not executed. So in this case Response.Write("test") is not executed.

Comment: That is it. $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; must be initialized in mobileinit event, otherwise it wont work correctly. I will put an example in my answer. Try it now.

Comment: Hi again, now it finally seems to work. But I have to initialize then mobileinit codeblock with ajax disabling event BEFORE referencing the standard jQuery .js file before it will work. Hmm.. I think I have to stydy your link about the JQM  page life cyclus to understand...

Answer (score 0):

I DID IT.....

DO NOT USE 
instructions described [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/asp-net-postbacks-not-triggering-with-jquery-mobile-1-0-final)

simply open jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js file
fine ajaxEnabled:!0 and change it to : ajaxEnabled:!1

now hit CTRL+F5 and joy the project while it continues ! ;)